# Django HTTP request to api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So i been trying to get this to work but at the same time i do not understand some of these code means. I'm sorry for making the question so long but i want to understand how these works.

I am trying to make a HTTP request to another API to do POST and GET method using django. Based on the website code example, which is this url: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/11/build-your-own-pokedex-with-django-mms-and-pokeapi.html

As i wanted to use HTTP Request on my API to call other API, therefore i wanted to get a better understanding of how these works and how to use it.

The code is at the bottom of the website. But i will just provide the code here so it is easier for you.

**website code**

```
from django_twilio.views import twilio_view
from twilio.twiml import Response
import requests
import json

BASE_URL = 'http://pokeapi.co'

def query_pokeapi(resource_uri):
    url = '{0}{1}'.format(BASE_URL, resource_uri)
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(response.text)
    return None

@twilio_view
def incoming_message(request):
    twiml = Response()

    body = request.POST.get('Body', '')
    body = body.lower()

    pokemon_url = '/api/v1/pokemon/{0}/'.format(body)
    pokemon = query_pokeapi(pokemon_url)

    if pokemon:
        sprite_uri = pokemon['sprites'][0]['resource_uri']
        description_uri = pokemon['descriptions'][0]['resource_uri']

        sprite = query_pokeapi(sprite_uri)
        description = query_pokeapi(description_uri)

        message = '{0}, {1}'.format(pokemon['name'], description['description'])
        image = '{0}{1}'.format(BASE_URL, sprite['image'])

        frm = request.POST.get('From', '')
        if '+44' in frm:
            twiml.message('{0} {1}'.format(message, image))
            return twiml
        twiml.message(message).media(image)
        return twiml

    twiml.message("Something went wrong! Try 'Pikachu' or 'Rotom'")
    return twiml
```

My question is:

1. i have read about the `request.POST` and `request.POST.get` but i still don't get it. Isn't `request.POST` = POST method/create function ?
2. what does `body.lower` mean ? Cant seems to find anything about it.
3. I am very confuse about this part

   ```
   sprite_uri = pokemon['sprites'][0]['resource_uri']
   description_uri = pokemon['descriptions'][0]['resource_uri']

   sprite = query_pokeapi(sprite_uri)
   description = query_pokeapi(description_uri)
   ```

is `pokemon['sprites']` refers to the sprites field in the api ?

4. What does this even means ?

   ```
       frm = request.POST.get('From', '')
       if '+44' in frm:
           twiml.message('{0} {1}'.format(message, image))
           return twiml
       twiml.message(message).media(image)
       return twiml
   ```

`request.POST.get('From', '')` Isn't POST where user enter data ? Where does 'From' come from? And what does this means ? `if '+44' in frm:` if +44 is found in frm ?

Comment: These are all really basic Python questions. Rather than trying to understand a big chunk of existing Django code, you should go and do an introductory Python tutorial first.

Answer (score 1):

ALL The questions are based on very basic python concepts, I recommend you go through python docs here [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

1. Diff in request.POST and request.POST.get()

   ```
   Ex request.post has following dict {'abc_key': 'abc_value'}
       than request.POST['abc_key'] will give 'abc_value'
       but  request.POST['xyz_key'] will throw error

       so we use default value to escape this error
       request.POST.get('xyz_key', "default_value")
       this will not give error if xyz_key is not found
   ```
2. body.lower

   This method returns a copy of the string in which all case-based 
    characters have been lowercased.

   check this link  [lower()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)
3. pokemon['sprites'][0]['resource_uri']
   this is serching in pokemon (which have dictionary values)

   Ex. pokemon = {'sprites':[{'resource_uri': 'res_value'}, 1, 2, 3 ]}
       so pokemon['sprites'][0]['resource_uri']  will give 'res_value'
4. frm = request.POST.get('From', '')  same as i said in 1st point
5. if '+44' in frm:
   this will return True if string '+44' is substring in frm 
   variable(string)

Comment: So `request.post` will display error if the key/field name is wrong while `request.post.get` will display None ?  But isnt request.post a post function ? Why am i getting the value if all im doing is sending data? At most i know that the response i get back is if the post function is success or fail.

Comment: So for example if i do a `request.post{'title': '12 Season', 'author': 'May'}` to a book api, does this means that i created an book object into the api ?

Comment: post is not sending data its request method (out of many) it says you have received an POST request and have data withing request.post , request will have data like.... request = {post: {1,2}, get:{1,2}} and you can access data based on request you receive either get or post

Comment: just do print(request) inside def incoming_message(request) and you will see all data request holds

Comment: wait, so the post is actually like a search ? eg: posting userId will get back the information of the userId given ?

Comment: i think you are confusing (request.post) this with import requests module, both are different

Comment: In this scenario post is like dictionary-key inside request variable